# Android ExpandableListView and CardView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, material-design

I would'like to use cardView for each group of an ExpendableListView. 
As in the first picture.
This is not my data, it's just for the idea of result. 
I want one block by group and each group with n rows .

[image]

I can do it like this

```
 <LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView />
                ...
                <TextView />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        ...

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView />
                ...
                <TextView />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But I'm afraid of performance.

With expendableListView I try to add separator and the best I can do :

[image]

But on pre Lollipop device, there is not a good result.

[image]

I hope someone will have an idea.

Comment: any luck , in finding the solution ?

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: I don't find solution with ExpendableView I switch and just use 1 recylcerView with multiple row different row. For space, I use margin on top or bottom

Comment: hi @Anthone can your share a bit of how you have achieved it?

Comment: Sorry @androlergic It's too far from now. But today i will do it with RecyclerView and different size of row

Comment: @Anthone I have achieved it using expandable list view. will share the solution soon. My problem was that the functionality was already designed using expandable. So I don't want to change the functionality that will cost a lot of time for me.